# InvalidCastException from List<T> to IEnumerable<T> only in 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, exception, casting

If i call that

```
var list = new List<Class1>();
Test((IEnumerable<Interface1>)list);
```

with

```
public interface Interface1
{

}

public static void Test(IEnumerable<Interface1> test)
{

}

public class Class1 : Interface1
{

}
```

I get an InvalidCastException with the 3.5 framework, but in 4 and 4.5 it's ok.  And I don't understand why, both have IEnumerable

If I check the list in 3.5 and 4.5 I can't see why I get an InvalidCastException

```
4.5:

public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

3.5:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

Comment: You had answer. Use `System.Linq`- `list.Cast<Interface1>()` it's working with all framework ;)

Comment: I use that workaround but I wanted to understand the reason of the restriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in 3.5 `IEnumerable<T>` is declared as

```
public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
```

but in 4.0 and newer it is declared as

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

The `out` is what allows [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) which is what you need to go from `List<Class1>();` to `IEnumerable<Interface1>`

In 3.5 you are only allowed to do `List<Class1>();` to `IEnumerable<Class1>` or `List<Interface1>();` to `IEnumerable<Interface1>`

---

As a workaround in 3.5 you can accomplish what you want by using the `Cast<T>()` LINQ method.

```
var list = new List<Class1>();
Test(list.Cast<Interface1>());
```

Answer (score 5):

In 3.5, the `IEnumerable<T>` interface was not covariant.  That was added in 4.0.

Covariance is required to cast to a type that is more derived, which is the case here (`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, which only became true in .NET 4.0.  In older versions it wasn't covariant (as the language didn't support that feature).